# PHP Class that handles multiple ways of SQL Server Querying

Tags: php, sql-server

I am looking for a class or a function, that handles multiple ways to access SQL Server via php.

So that I can have one connect(), select/exec(), disconnect() function.

instead of having seperate functions for each type of connection.

1. mssql_connect
2. sqlsrv_connect
3. odbc_connect

I was trying to use the logic similar to this.

if extension 'mssql_connect' exists

then connect via mssql_connect.

And etc, with other methods.

But I was wondering if someone already had such a function/class written, that they could share.

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to do yourself, but it would be an endlessly long rabbit hole creating a wrapper for universal db queries. Check GitHub?

Comment: Is [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) sufficient?

Comment: Nope, does not help me at all. As I said I'm not looking for many ways to connect to sql server, I am looking for a class that does them all conditionally if they able to do so.